# WPF passing button content from button?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button

Let's say I have two button defined as below:

```
<Button Content="ButtonA" Command="{Binding [SomeTerminal].SomeCommand}"/>
<Button Content="ButtonB" Command="{Binding [SomeTerminal].SomeCommand}"/>
```

May I know if it's possible to grab the content of the button? Meaning when user click the first button, I can get `ButtonA` in my `SomeCommand` method?

Comment: The buttons have no names, do you want the content? Also what does the Command look like?

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd: Thanks for reminding the misleading information

Comment: You can use CommandParameters,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a 'pure' MVVM solution you would need to put data in the ViewModel and bind the contents of  the buttons to this data to display it. You could then also pass the bound data to the command through a Command parameter.

```
<Button Content="{Binding SomeDataA}" 
        Command="{Binding [SomeTerminal].SomeCommand}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding SomeDataA}" />
<Button Content="{Binding SomeDataB}" 
        Command="{Binding [SomeTerminal].SomeCommand}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding SomeDataB}" />
```

Getting UI data from a View is considered bad practice because it creates a dependency in the ViewModel on the View making it harder to test.

Answer (score 5):

you can use a CommandParameter:

```
<Button Content="ButtonA" Command="{Binding [SomeTerminal].SomeCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=Content}" />
<Button Content="ButtonB" Command="{Binding [SomeTerminal].SomeCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=Content}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this,

```
<Button x:Name="BtnA" Content="ButtonA" Command="{Binding [SomeTerminal].SomeCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=BtnA, Path=Content}" />
```

or

```
<Button Content="ButtonA" Command="{Binding [SomeTerminal].SomeCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```

Comment: ButtonA is the content, not the name, it was wrong in the question, too.