# On button click I want to send the button text to viewModel (MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf

MVVM: I have a nested button that I would like to extract text from when clicking it.

As you know that you cant call the button in the code behind if its nested, 
So basically I would like to click this nested button then from XAML I would like to send the text of that button to my viewModel.

I have been searching for days and I still cant seem to get a good enough answer

I have tried binding - two and updating the source but I dont know if that is the right approach

```
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate x:Name="dataTemp">

                                <!-- Declaring a button-->
                                <Button x:Name="btnItem" d:DataContext="{x:Static local:ItemDesign.Instance}" 
                                        Background="White" Height="60" Width="300">

                                    <!--Content Grid (Main) -->
                                    <Grid x:Name="container" Height="60" Width="300">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <!--Colour circle-->
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                            <!--Full Name-->
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                        <!--Colour Circle-->
                                        <Border Grid.Column="0" Padding="6">
                                            <Border Background="#FF1869B6" 
                                                    Width="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}}"
                                                    CornerRadius="25">
                                                <TextBlock  x:Name="txtInitials" Text="{Binding Initials, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                            Foreground="White" FontSize="25" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semilight"/>
                                            </Border>
                                        </Border>
                                        <!-- EO Colour Circle-->

                                        <!-- Full Name Textblock-->
                                        <TextBlock  x:Name="txtFullName"
                                                    Text="{Binding FullName, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                    Grid.Column="2"
                                                    Padding="15 0 0 0"
                                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                    Foreground="#FF1869B6"
                                                    TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"                                  
                                                    FontSize="25"/>
                                        <!-- EO Full Name Textblock-->

                                    </Grid>

                                    <!-- Button Styling -->
                                    <Button.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
                                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
                                                </Trigger>

                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=btnItem, Path=IsPressed}" Value="true">

                                                    <!--
                                                    <Setter Property="Button" Value="{Binding FullName, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
                                                    -->
                                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Button.Style>
                                    <!-- EO Button Styling -->

                                </Button>
                                <!-- EO Declaring a button-->

                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>

                </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <!-- EO Patient List -->
```

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22243736/wpf-passing-button-content-from-button Also notice button has content property and no text property, so button can contain other elements and extracting text from it can be not so straightforward.

Comment: The way to "send" data from the view to the view model in MVVM is to use a binding.

Comment: Would it not be easier to use `ListBox` and a `SelectedValue`? Those names in xaml are worrying.

Answer (score 1):

There's several ways to do what you're wanting using pure MVVM but I'll answer it one way and let you resolve the logic into whatever works for you.

The purpose of this example is to pass the `Content` of a `Button`, when clicked, to the ViewModel and display it in a `TextBlock` on the main `Window`.  This is done in MVVM and uses no code behind.

First there's the Main Window that has the XAML I believe you need (or similar) and following is all of the code to make this example work MVVM.
In this example I pass the `Content` of the `Button` back via a parameter in the command.  NOTE: A button's `Content` does not have to be and in many cases will not be text.  I am converting the object to text in my command but you'll need to ensure this works in your XAML.

```
<Window x:Class="ButtonContentExample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ButtonContentExample"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Height="450"
    Width="800">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ExampleViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TestResult}"
               Margin="12"
               FontSize="20" />
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TestItemViewModel}">
                <Button Content="{Binding Value}"
                        Command="{Binding TestCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" 
                        Width="50"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Apologies for combining all of the code but wanted to give you the entire source. Below is the RelayCommand, ViewModelBase, ExampleViewModel, and TestItemViewModel.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace ButtonContentExample
{
    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, null) { }
        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
        {
            ExecuteAction = execute;
            CanExecutePredicate = canExecute ?? new Predicate<object>(obj => true);
        }
        public Action<object> ExecuteAction { get; }
        public Predicate<object> CanExecutePredicate { get; }
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => CanExecutePredicate(parameter);
        public void Execute(object parameter) => ExecuteAction(parameter);
    }

    public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void Notify<T>(ref T t, T value, [CallerMemberName] string name = "")
        {
            t = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    public class ExampleViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private string testResult;
        private ObservableCollection<TestItemViewModel> items = new ObservableCollection<TestItemViewModel>();
        public ExampleViewModel()
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) Items.Add(new TestItemViewModel(this) { Value = i });
        }
        public ObservableCollection<TestItemViewModel> Items
        {
            get => items;
            set => Notify(ref items, value);
        }

        public string TestResult
        {
            get => testResult;
            set => Notify(ref testResult, value);
        }
    }

    public class TestItemViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private int value;
        private string result;
        public TestItemViewModel(ExampleViewModel parent)
        {
            Parent = parent;
            TestCommand = new RelayCommand(obj => Result = obj.ToString());
        }
        public int Value
        {
            get => value;
            set => Notify(ref this.value, value);
        }

        public string Result
        {
            get { return result; }
            set
            {
                Notify(ref result, value);
                Parent.TestResult = value;
            }
        }

        public RelayCommand TestCommand { get; }
        public ExampleViewModel Parent { get; }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]